# rewrite url with slash using htaccess

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, seo

Hello someone pls help me

**I have this url which is dynamic**

```
 productSearch.php?id_category=8&id_size=23&id_colour=93
```

and i have to do this in

```
productSearch/8/23/93
```

i have try

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/(.+)\.php[^\s]* [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+id_category(?:\.php)?\?id=([0-9]+) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ id_category/%1? [R,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
 RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

its remove .php only but not putting slash.

Pls some one give me some idea

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule productSearch/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)$ productSearch.php?id_category=$1&id_size=$2&id_colour=$3 [L]
```

Comment: sorry but url comes in dynamacally so its not working

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? What type of urls you will have ?

Comment: productSearch.php?id_category=8&id_size=23&id_colour=93

Comment: I am not getting you. Why will the above rewrite url not work in your case ?

Comment: What is the url for css & js ? Are they also getting rewritten ?

Comment: its somthing like <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/main.css" type="text/css"> but not working

Comment: Make 1 more .htaccess inside templates folder and make it   `rewriteengine off`

Comment: Create new .htaccess inside templates folder and write `RewriteEngine Off` and save and then check again.

Comment: Put a slash in front of the css/image path.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^productSearch/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ productSearch.php?id_category=$1&id_size=$2&id_colour=$3 [L]
```

Try this. Put in your url following links: `<a href="productSearch/8/23/93">lala</a>`

If you want that only a numeric path will be rewritten you could use `([0-9]+)` instead of `([^/]*)`

Comment: sorry but url comes in dynamacally so its not working